# SQL command to find the row with Second Largest value in a database

Tags: sql, database, max

I have a database table with two columns First and Second. ( marks of two tests ).
I need to find the row(student) with the max difference among the two columns.(test marks)
That is the row that has shown the most change between its two columns.

Though I can find the row with the highest difference, I can't find the row with the second highest and third, and so forth.

What is the SQL command to do so.

**Note :** I am using http://freesqldatabase.com through http://phpmyadmin.co/

Comment: "Assume you own column names if you want" - no. If you want help here, ask a specific question, provide the table information, some sample data, and the output you'd like to obtain from that data. This site is not for "guess at my problem, figure out what I want, and do all the work for me" questions. If you want help, at least put the effort into providing information in your question. Don't be helpless - if it's not worth your effort to ask properly, it's certainly not worth ours to help you.

Comment: Show us your effort, and we can help you along.

Comment: Also, tell us your vendor as some of the relevant syntax is vendor and version specific.

Comment: @KenWhite Hey. I have edited the question as asked. I added every thing I was confused about. Please help.

Comment: I still see no table definition (what types are "First" and "Second"?), no sample data, and no desired output. Once again: if it's not worth your effort to ask the question, don't expect us to put the effort into answering it.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what SQL dialect freesqldatabase.com supports, but the following is pretty standard SQL and should work on most databases:

```
SELECT score1, score2, abs(score1 - score2) AS difference FROM scores ORDER BY abs(score1 - score2) DESC
```

Of course, replace the `score1` & `score2` columns as well as the `scores` table with your actual column and table names.